# "to be/is/get used"

Tags: passive-voice

Why in this sentences use phrase "to be" instead of **is** or **get**?
What did the author wants to say?

> Polymorphism is a feature that allows one interface **to be** used for a general class of actions.

Comment: Because that is the way the language works! _Allow_ is one of the verbs that are followed by the [infinitive](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/to-infinitives). _Allow [it] is used_ or _Allow [it] get used_ are both incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under a traditional analysis, only finite verbs form predicates and require subjects.  Using a finite verb like "is" or "gets" would break the clause structure because there just aren't enough subjects to go around.

> Polymorphism is<sub>1</sub> a feature that allows<sub>2</sub> one interface to be used for a general class of actions.

The first finite verb in this sentence is "is".  Its clause takes "polymorphism" as its simple subject, and "feature" is the verb's simple argument.  The second finite verb is "allows".  That clause takes "that" as its subject, with "interface" as the verb's simple object, and the rest of the sentence as an object complement.

> One interface is<sub>1</sub> used for a general class of actions.

This sentence has one finite verb, and the clause takes "interface" as its simple subject.

Here's the conflict:  In the first sentence, "interface" isn't available as a simple subject for anything.  It already has a role as an object.

> * Polymorphism is<sub>1</sub> a feature that allows<sub>2</sub> one **interface** is<sub>3</sub> used for a general class of actions.

If we treat "interface" as the simple subject of "is<sub>3</sub>", then "allows<sub>2</sub>" has no object and the sentence makes no sense.  Alternately, if we treat "interface" as the simple object of "allows<sub>2</sub>", then "is<sub>3</sub>" has no subject and the sentence makes no sense.

We could, of course, make sense of things if we split the relevant clauses into separate sentences:

> One interface can<sub>1</sub> be used for a general class of actions.  Polymorphism is<sub>2</sub> a feature that allows<sub>3</sub> this behavior.

Here, "this behavior" refers to the entire contents of the preceding sentence.  Each finite verb has its own subject, and no constituent has any conflict regarding what grammatical role it should play.

Comment: Greenbaum Sidney, Nelson Gerald C. An Introduction to English Grammar, 2013; 3.18 Finite and non-finite verb phrases. is it? Verb phrases are either finite or non-finite. A finite verb phrase is one that carries a
contrast in tense between present and past, and may also be marked for person and
number. In a finite verb phrase the first or only verb is finite, and the other verbs
(if any) are non-finite. In a non-finite verb phrase all the verbs are non-finite. Play and
played are finite verbs in these sentences:
[1] We play football every day.

Comment: Yes.  Non-finite forms include participles, gerunds and infinitives.  The phrase "to be used for a general class of actions" is an infinitive phrase.  The verbs involved are the full infinitive "to be" and the participle "used", with "for a general class of actions" as a prepositional phrase acting as an adjunct.  The finite verb "allows" in the original model licenses both a direct object ("one interface") and an object complement (the infinitive phrase in question).